# Best way to store/read data in sqllite with characters such as * '?

Tags: sqlite, escaping, symbols

I'm using SQLite and I need to save and read data with just any type of symbols. Is there any way to escape this symbols?

I'm trying replaceAll("\'","\'") but there may be more symbols I don't know about that may have problems, is there any method that does this for me?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, `'` is the only character that needs quoting inside SQL strings.
However, you can avoid this question altogether, and prevent the overhead of your program escaping and then SQLite unescaping the string, by using *parameters*, which are literal values that get substituted into SQL.

How exactly this works depends on what language and driver you use, but typically looks like this:

```py
db.execute("INSERT INTO Users(Name, Passwd, Expired) VALUES(?, ?, 0)",
           ["Bob", "!*\\$%&:?"])
```